# After animation touchable opacity not working

Tags: react-native

In my react native project, touchable opacity doesn't work after I animated it. I animated its size, X and Y Positions. Nothing working both the press and also its opacity change. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

After trying it with other options i noticed one can use TouchableWithoutFeedback. Worked. But still dont know why TouchableOpacity cant help achieve the same.

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress="{triggerCall}">
   <Animated.View
     style="{["
     styles.button,
     styles.secondary,
     callStyle,
     opacity,
     ]}
   >
     <Entypo name="call" size="{20}" color="#2a5ff0" />
   </Animated.View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```